# Compose: custom top bar, render (or not) a navigationIcon based on a nullable callback parameter

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Given the following code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CustomBar(title: String, onBackPressed: (() -> Unit)? = null) {
    TopAppBar(
        title = {
            Text(
                title,
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontFamily = appFontFamily,
                    fontSize = 24.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(600)
                )
            )
        },
        navigationIcon = {
            if (onBackPressed != null) {
                IconButton(onClick = { onBackPressed() }) {
                    Icon(
                        painterResource(id = drawable.ic_topbar_back),
                        contentDescription = null
                    )
                }
            }
        },
        backgroundColor = Color.White,
        elevation = 0.dp,
        contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
    )
}
```

My intention is to:

- Create a reusable component to add custom `TopAppBar` in my application
- I need to provide a title to all bars
- I optionally can send a callback to react to back presses, if the callback is not null then I want to show the back icon, if the callback is null then no `navigationIcon` must be rendered

The above code works. The only problem is that if I send a null callback, an empty space is rendered as if Compose is leaving space for a `navigationIcon`.

What I want to achieve: if I send the parameter `onBackPressed` as *NULL* then it should be equals as setting `navigationIcon` to *NULL* when creating the `TopAppBar`.

How can I achieve that? Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`navigationIcon` is nullable. If you don't want your TopAppBar to have a navigation icon, you have to pass null. Currently, you always pass a non null composable function, which is empty if `onBackPressed` is null. You have to move your if condition one level up:

```
navigationIcon = if (onBackPressed == null) null else {
    {
        IconButton(onClick = onBackPressed) {
            Icon(
                painterResource(id = drawable.ic_topbar_back),
                contentDescription = null
            )
        }
    }
}
```